# How to cast a Pandas Dataframe column into 'list' type?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, casting

Following the [Pandas explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method documentation, one can explode a list in a row into multiple rows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1, 2, 3], 'foo', None, [3, 4]], 'B': 1})
df.explode('A')
```

However, the DataFrame() I get from a database contains lists that are seen as strings :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["[1, 2, 3]", 'foo', None, "[3, 4]"], 'B': 1})
df.explode('A')
# Does not fail, but does not explode "[1, 2, 3]"
```

Outside Pandas, I use [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) but don't know how to make it work for my column.

How to cast my 'A' column as list so that explode('A') works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except Exception:
        return x


df['A']=df['A'].apply(f)
df.explode('A')

      A  B
0     1  1
0     2  1
0     3  1
1   foo  1
2  None  1
3     3  1
3     4  1
```

Comment: use same with literal eval, its safer than eval

Comment: if this does exactly the same thing really

Comment: [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)